# Calling a javascript function without arguments

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call a javascript function without paranthesis? ().  In the below code, from a book, has the line,

```
http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
```

If there is no paramenters in the function definition, can we call without arguments?

```js
function getServerText() {
  var myurl = 'ajax.php';
  myRand = parseInt(Math.random() * 999999999999999);
  var modurl = myurl + "?rand=" + myRand;
  http.open("GET", modurl, true);
  http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse;
  http.send(null);
}


function useHttpResponse() {
  if (http.readyState == 4) {
    if (http.status == 200) {
      var mytext = http.responseText;
      document.getElementById('myPageElement')
        .innerHTML = mytext;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById('myPageElement')
      .innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: The only situation where you can omit parenthesis is when using the `new` keyword. Or you use something hacky like `setTimeout(func, 0)`, but that's not really reasonable IMO. *edit:* As Niet said, in this case you are not calling the function and you don't want to. You are assigning a function as **callback** so that other code can call the function *later*.

Comment: Here `http.onreadystatechange = useHttpResponse` is a reference to `useHttpResponse` function. You can do it partly because functions are first class objects in JavaScript. You can assign a function to a variable: `var square = function(x) { return x*x; }`. You can even have an array of functions: `var fs = [square, function(x) { return x*x*x; }]` You might find it interesting that yes you can invoke a function with a syntax like this: `square.apply(null, [5])`. Notice how I'm calling `apply` function on `square` function.

Answer (score 3):

When assigning an event handler, you don't want to call the function, you're giving it a reference to a function, which will be called later.

So... no. `()` is used to mean "call this function", in this case with no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same way of :

```js
function add2values(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

const objX = { name: 'xyz', myAdd: null }

objX.myAdd = add2values

console.log( objX.myAdd(1, 2) ) // -> 3
```